# Mutt not working inside Crontab but works out of it

Tags: cron, mutt

After research the whole Internet can't find a solution to it.

I have a script which is working perfectly when I execute it from terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash

zip -r -j Tato.zip Csv

rm -r Csv/*.*

echo "blahblahblah" | mutt -s "Test" email@gmail.com -a Tato.zip

rm *.zip
```

but actually it does not work when I put it inside a crontab.

```
55 15  * * 7 /home/pi/Script.sh
```

wanted it to be executed on Sundays at 15.55.

And this is the output that /var/log/syslog tells me

```
Nov  1 15:55:01 raspberrypi sSMTP[3939]: Unable to locate mail
Nov  1 15:55:01 raspberrypi sSMTP[3939]: Cannot open mail:25
Nov  1 15:55:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[3936]: (pi) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of     output; but got status 0x0001, #012)
```

Don't know what to do anymore.

All help will be appreciated.

Comment: Most likely the problem is a difference in the environment that crontab is running the script vs. your terminal. Add `env >/tmp/env.txt` to the beginning of your script and compare the results when run by crontab and your terminal.

Comment: At the end, just changed mutt for ssmtp and thats it. thanks anyway! ;)